# Mysql query for reduction 2 data

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1 : Buyer

```
UserID      Value 
1          5000
```

Table 2 : Seller

```
UserID      Value
1           2000
2           1500
3           4000
```

so here is case
im a buyer want to buy 5000 point from a seller
so i trade in market and fill form order.
and then then backend will be proceed to my 5000 order to a seller
logic is im order 5000 and 
seller with ID 1 i got 2000 (-3000)
seller with ID 2 i got 1500 (-1500)
seller with ID 3 i got 1500 ( 0 = i got my 5000 point)

and then seller with ID 3 that data will be updated to 2500
and seller with ID 1 and 2 will be 0 or i added status field is success.
Can someone help, what query should I make to get that?

thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what you want in  this case exactly??

Comment: @HarshPanchal i want to know query mysql or function for reduction my order point to point seller

Comment: What you need is Update `Table 2 : Seller` based on `Table 1 : Buyer`. However both can not work in one query. First SELECT data  from table2 and see how much amount you want and after that Update table 2 with new reduced data.